# What is the purpose of glass element?

Tags: optics

I've seen video about range finder and interested in purpose of one of element. Rangefinder works at 120 GHz and annotation in video says that it is glass lens and its purpose is to bend radiowaves and for thermal isolation. But it doesn't look like lens. What is the name of such element? Seems like prism, but i have not found something similar.

[image]

Comment: Link to video will help people answer your quesion.

Comment: you said that it is used for radio waves ... then that is not an optic element ... possibly a wave guide of some sort

Comment: StainlessSteelRat. Thanks. It's good idea. Here is the link to video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Phj8u58Gi9s.

Comment: jsotola. Video says that rangefinder works at 120G. I not sure whether it radio or already can be considered as far infrared. But glass works not very good with ir and rf. So cannot understand why it is glass element, and purpose of element. Video annotation mention that it is for radiowaves refraction and for thermal insulation (because it is industrial rangefinder). And they have a lot of different emitter types for their rangefinders. https://en.feejoy.com/products/radar-level-transmitter.